# How to change resolution of a main window with a user control inside it?

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

I am trying to add `UserControl` to `MainWindow`. And I want to set property of the Screen resolution of the controls also automatically. Please help me for that screen

Answer (score 0):

Please be more clear while asking a question. Do you want the user control to fill inside your window or you want to re-size the window width to the size of the control within it?

If you want the user control inside the window to fit inside the window you could use the same width as the window excluding the border for the user control or use "*" for the user control width so that it can occupy the entire space.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: But I guess he is probably asking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want responsive layout, then you should divide UI proportionally. As a consequence of this, you can set proportion what you want and this proportion will be resized proportionally depending on your display size. For example, you have `FooUserControl`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <local:FooUserControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

The size of `Height` and `Width` can have three values:

**Fixed** - it is fixed size. (1/96 inch)
**Auto** - it takes as much space as needed by the placed control
**Star (*)** - the available width/height is divided evenly among all columns/rows proportionally.

Comment: I want to extended the  controls also when the screen is maximized

Comment: @Bharath.M this solution will work when the screen is maximized.